# save and reuse computed data in widget build: flutter

Tags: flutter

The question is how to prevent calls that compute data in build.

Example (a simplistic one)

```
for (var map in something)
...
child: Row(
  children: [
    Text(getActualDate(map['days'])),
    Text(getActualDate(map['days']))
  ],
),
...
```

Here the getActualDate function has been called and the result available. How can I save and reuse that result and not call getActualDate again?

Answer (score 0):

By using state management, like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)